# Mount LinkResource wicket link from java - to php

Tags: java, cakephp, wicket

I'm using wicket, to make a pdf, but I want the link of the pdf to be called by cake php.

To do this, I know I need to mount the resource of my ResourceLink:

Here is my code:

```
private void downloadReport() 

{

    ResourceLink pl= new  ResourceLink("printlink", new ByteArrayResource("application/pdf")
    {

        @Override
        protected byte[] getData(IResource.Attributes attributes)
        {
            JasperPrint jp = donwloadReport();
           return createReport(jp);

        }

        @Override
        protected void configureResponse(AbstractResource.ResourceResponse response, IResource.Attributes attributes)
        {
            super.configureResponse(response, attributes); 
            response.setFileName("operedb.pdf"+System.currentTimeMillis());
            response.setCacheDuration(Duration.NONE);

        }


    });

pl.add(new AttributeModifier("title", "crate pdf"));

add(pl);
}
```

I tried with

```
ResourceReference resourceReference = new ResourceReference("rssProducer"){
     RSSReaderResource rssResource = new RSSReaderResource();
```

But is not working. Where is my mistake?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the resource in your application?

```
this.mountResource( "getpdf", new ResourceReference( "pdfResource" )
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -587743631155996193L;
        PDFResource pdfResource = new PDFResource();

        @Override
        public IResource getResource()
        {
            return this.pdfResource;
        }
    } );
```

Where `PDFResource` extends `AbstractResource`